# Unable to sort values alphabetically A-Z and call ToList() function

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort the values of Agency alphabetically A-Z and call the ToList() function

```
public static List<AgencyTable> GetAgency()
{
   using (myEntities db = new MyEntities())
   {
      return db.Agency.ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem? You know `List.Sort`? or alternativly `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy`?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public static List<AgencyTable> GetAgency()
{
   using (myEntities db = new MyEntities())
   {
      return db.Agency.OrderBy(a => a.<<whatever field to sort by>>).ToList();
   }
}
```